# Package restore fails on Azure

Tags: azure, teamcity, nuget, build-automation, nuget-package

I have two virtual machines running on Azure.
One is running a build server (TeamCity), and one is running Visual Studio 2013.

Both are building the same project, in which NuGet package restore is used.
All packages are restored normally, except for AjaxControlToolkit.

`nuget.targets(89, 9): Unable to find version '7.0607' of package 'AjaxControlToolkit'.`

The package is restored normally when running on my local machine.
Is this an accessibility issue on Azure, how would I debug this?

Comment: what package source are you using to restore your packages from?

Comment: plain old NuGet.org (https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/)
I use multiple packages from this source, but AjaxControlToolkit is the only one to fail to restore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with NuGet v2.7: https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/3628
Perhaps use nuget v2.6 until a fix has been shipped?

Comment: I cannot test it for now (my test Azure service has exceeded its limits).
I haven't added the NuGet binary to this project, so I might have to switch NuGet version in Teamcity.
On the other machine, running Visual Studio, the solution was to manually copy the binaries to teh repository folder. My guess is that they will address this issue soon.